# How to filter just the name of the Object on Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-pipe

I've got a problem. I have a list of cities, but when I use the search-bar, I just want the cities with the same name to appear.

Currently i'm trying this:

```
   <ion-searchbar
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
      [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
      (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
    </ion-searchbar>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities | orderBy: name | filter: selectedCity">
          <ion-label>{{city.name}}</ion-label>
    <button (click)="onActive(city.detalhe.id)" *ngIf="city.active" ion-button outline item-right>Desativar</button>
    <button (click)="onActive(city.detalhe.id)" *ngIf="!city.active" ion-button outline item-right>Ativar</button>
        </ion-item>
```

But I know it will never works 'cause i'm sending the object city to the pipe 'filter' and not the name, how can I send just the name for the pipe? I need the object for the method 'onActive'

The Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
name: "filter",
pure: false
})

export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => {
        for (let field in conditions) {
            if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
}
```

And 'selectedCity' is a String. When I try the pipe out with others strings, It works. Another point, I need to filter comparing the name of the object but I need the whole object after this.

Answer (score 1):

Well to begin with it looks like you'd need to send [2 parameters](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe) to the filter. The first being the literal 'name', the second selectedCity unquoted in the *ngFor of <ion-item>.
Then you could filter by items[field] !== selectedCity - where field would contain 'name'

I take it you've got the orderBy Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479995/495157)

You did see the comments below in the order by example link too... avoid using pipes for orderby.. Do it in components. I would address doing both at the component level personally.

Comment: Can you edit the pipe? I do not know how to do that.