# Custom OrderPipe is not working in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angularjs-orderby

I have created a custom pipe to sort the array of objects but the pipe is not working ?
my array of [ {name , population , variable }] . i want to sort the array of object according to population

PIPE:

```
import {Pipe , PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

     @Pipe ({
    name:'order'
    })

    export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value: any[], property: any, descending?: boolean): any {
    if (!value || value.length) {
      return value;
    }

    value.sort((first: any, second: any): number => {
        return first[property] > second[property] ? 1 : -1;
    });

    if (descending) {
      return value.reverse();
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul>
 <li *ngFor="let items of results"
   {{items.name | order:'population':'true'  }}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This kind of question has been asked a lot... For example..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461203/angular-2-how-to-apply-orderby/35479995#35479995  Also it's not a best practise. Use services... See here https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have like this

```
<li *ngFor="let items of results | order:'population':'true'">
   {{items.name}}
</li>
```

Also your Pipe has a problem you need to check the length of array as 0, otherwise it will always return the same array without sorting

```
 if (!value || value.length == 0) {
      return value;
 }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/MuAysQEWRLo47isli0DL?p=preview)**

Comment: It is not working 
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let items of results | order:'population':'true' " [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':items.variable}"   >
        {{items.name}}

this is my html and the results is fetched from the server .

Comment: can you post the json

Comment: results is array of objects and i want to sort the array according to population property of object .

Comment: which json are you telling about

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `items.name` to the pipe.

This is a `string` not having a property `population`.

Comment: so How can i do that .. i want just items.name to be shown on browser

Answer (score 0):

I've found a great npm package with some common reusable pipes. May be use https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#orderby?

Comment: Are you sure about that? That package definitely is an Angular2 module. Isn't pipes something that was introduced in Angular 2 and up?

Comment: @TarikSahni  It's working for Angular2+ and even 4+ :)