# Sorting in angular and webapi

Tags: javascript, angular, sql-server-2012

I Need the list to be sorted in ascending order by `Name` before rendering it.
Guys if you know how to sort from database( MS sql server 2012) Please tell me

employe.component.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employeeService.employeeList">
<td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
<td>{{employee.DOB}}</td>
<td>{{employee.Salary}}</td>
<td>
<a class="btn" (click)="showForEdit(employee)">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn text-danger" (click)="onDelete(employee.EmployeeId)">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Then apply a sort to `employeeService.employeeList` before displaying in DOM. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dirty way, please refer to the third response in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461203/angular-2-how-to-apply-orderby).
But in [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#!#no-filter-pipe) it's mentionned that these type of pipes can reduce performance. Personally i do sorting from the data base it's much better

Comment: yes i was trying from database but i don't know how to sort in asc in ms sql server 2012