# Angular - How to sort by last name pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

For my Angular project, I want to display the EmpID values in a combo box and have them sorted by the last name.

Here's an html snippet where I'm trying to implement the pipe.

```html
    <select id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{emp.EmpID | orderByLast}}</option>
    </select>
```

and here's  my orderByLast.pipe.ts :

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'orderByLast' })

export class OrderByLast implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<string>): Array<string> {
        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
        return array;
    }
}
```

and here's my emp-info.ts array:

```js
export class EmpInfo {
    EmpKey: number;
    EmpID: string;
    Firstname: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmpStat: string;
    StartDate: Date;
    AdjustedStart: Date;
    Anniversary: number;
    PTOYear: number;
    STDLTD: number;
    Uncharged: number;
    ETOEarned: number;
    ETORequests: number;
    ETORemaining: number;
    PTOBase: number;
    PTOCarry: number;
    PTOBorrowed: number;
    PTOBalance: number;
    PTORequests: number;
    PTORemaining: number;
}
```

Comment: have u tried something?

Comment: What is the structure of an `emp` object ? Nobody can guess it...

Comment: Do not sort with pipes. If you really want to anyway, then just read the documentation. You'll need to implement the `transform` method.

Comment: @torazaburo how would I sort this without using a pipe?

Comment: In your component's TS logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a `transform` function:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'orderByLast' })

export class OrderByLast implements PipeTransform {
  transform() { // add your object as a parameter to transform()
    //write your code to do the sort
  }
}
```

See the 'Custom Pipes' section here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html (Please note that as @torazaburo pointed it out it's not recommended to do sorts using pipes which is also explained in the link under the 'Appendix: No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe' section.)

Comment: It's odd that you would cite a reference which recommends **against** doing sorting with pipes (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-).

Comment: You pointed this out to the person asking as well - it's up to them whether they'll go and read this and adhere to it, or not. Let me do a quick update to my post.

Comment: @torazaburo I've updated by post with the code that i put in orderbylast.pipe.ts and it's just printing out a blank combo box. what would I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

See this example. I implemented this `orderBy` pipe few months ago in my own app.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650432/5556177