# Custom pipe to sort array of array

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have a array of array having two elements each, i.e. `arr[a[2]]`. Index 0 is name and index 1 is size . I want a pipe to sort the array of array according to size ie index 1 .

Example:

```
arr [ [ 'hello' , '1' ] , [ 'how' , '5' ] , [ 'you' , '12' ] , [ 'are' , '6' ] ]
```

Output of pipe should be :

```
arr [ [ 'hello' , '1' ] , [ 'how' , '5' ] , [ 'are' , '6' ] , [ 'you' , '12' ] ]
```

HTML file:

```
<p> {{items  | custompipe }}</p>
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? This isn't a code writing service; [read the docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) and have a go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am a new learner , please help

Comment: Then **read the docs**, we aren't here for tutorials either.

Comment: use the search, something like this should get you started.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe/35158836#35158836

Comment: @Zuriel thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use a pipe for sorting. See the link here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Rather, add code in your component to perform your sort.

Here is an example. This one filters, but you could change it to sort instead.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    filteredProducts: IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

    }

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
              product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts()
                .subscribe(products => {
                    this.products = products;
                    this.filteredProducts = this.products;
                },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I love your videos on pluralsight, they've helped me immensely in my learning.   This answer was helpful to me because I have been using a OrderBySort pipe, even though I know of the performance ramifications.  Its nice to see a better way to to do it and I plan on refactoring some of my code.  Thanks!

Comment: See DeborahK's comment here for the link to her complete solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780843/angular-4-filter-search-custom-pipe and https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/ on how to properly handle filtering without using pipes.