# Angular 4 - Setting variable to index of for loop

Tags: angular

I have a simple loop like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let treatment of data.treatments; let order = index">
    {{treatment.order}}
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="treatment.name.dutch" >
</div>
```

Now I would like to set `treatment.order = order` in my template code. So that the list would always be

1...
2...
3...

But also that the variable treatment.order would then have the corresponding order in the list. I can't seem to find a way to do this

Comment: Create a simple pipe and add a new property at each treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a sort pipe for sorting the array

[More about pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

[stackoverflow question about sorting pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe)

Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let treatment of data.treatments | sortOrder; let order = index">
    {{treatment.order}}
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="treatment.name.dutch" >
</div>
```