# How can I sort my data by name in a *NgFor list?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am working on a new project on Angular 6.

I have a list of students with a *NgFor :

(html)

```
<tr *ngFor="let kk of Repdata | filterdata: queryString : 'name' ; let ind = index">

    <td>{{ind + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{kk.name}}</td>
    <td>{{kk.prenom}}</td>
```

(filterdata is use for a seachbar)

typescript :

```
GetUser(){
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getUser/')
           .map((response: Response) => response.json())
}
```

javascript :

```
app.get("/api/getUser",function(req,res){
    model.find({},function(err,data){
              if(err){
                  res.send(err);
              }
              else{
                  res.send(data);
                  }
          });
  })
```

In my table, I have my data ordered by id, but I want to order it by name.  I don't know how to.

Comment: You can accomplish that by creating a custom pipe (in this case, a sort pipe). I would suggest you to take inspiration from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe

Comment: You can use `array.sort` method to do this.

Comment: You can check this for 5+ Angular 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-order-pipe

Answer (score 2):

if you just want your data sorted by name outside of the Database you can use the `sort()` function as explained here [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

you could also use the Sort function provided by mongodb as it seems you re using mongoose. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

if u want to just sort it in the Angular view you can use a custome sort pipe as explained here: [Angular 2 OrderBy Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe)

edit:

You shouldnt use Pipes for Filtering / Sorting as they are very unperformant as stated here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: As a sidenote, [dynamic filtering/sorting/grouping pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform sorting by installing DataTable in your app. It can also used to perform pagination.

You can install DataTable by running following command in angular 6:

```
npm i angular-6-datatable --save
```

For complete guide, go through this below link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable