# Angular orderBy pipe

Tags: angular

I want to order my result by a property name but the following gives me an error:

```
*ngFor="let s of rslt| order by:wind_park">
```

what i get from back-end:

```
data = [
  { turbine_name: "Baynne ", wind_park: "Bayone" },
  { turbine_name: "Salstiegl ", wind_park: "Salzst" },
  { turbine_name: "Chradurga - SLL2", wind_park: "Chiarga" },
  { turbine_name: "Moilishte ", wind_park: "Mogihte" },
  { turbine_name: "Mogshte ", wind_park: "Mogshte" }
]
```

How can I order it and what's the best practice? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You have to create your own custom orderBy pipe by yourself then use it

Comment: @KamranKhatti how to write it?

Comment: Submitting a proper fix hold on

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create your own OrderBy pipe to satisfy your needs, [lodash](https://lodash.com/) is a cool library which has bunch of ready made functions which do the trick `orderBy`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { orderBy } from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
 name: "orderBy"
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(array: any, sortBy: string, order?: string): any[] {
 const sortOrder = order ? order : 'asc'; // setting default ascending order

  return orderBy(array, [sortBy], [sortOrder]);
  }
}
```

Usage in template

```
<div *ngFor="let w of data | orderBy: 'wind_park'">{{ w.wind_park}}</div> //default will sort ascending
```

for descending pass the desc in pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let w of data | orderBy: 'wind_park': 'desc'">{{ w.wind_park}}</div>
```

Make sure you declare pipe in your module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:  [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ OrderByPipe ], // declare pipe here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
 })
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yqqtva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: i have implemented it but it does not sort ,i get a json file from back end,there is a field wind_park,but it does not sort it

Comment: Can you share your back end response so that I can get idea whats the actual response?

Comment: updated my question with what i get from api,hope its helful

Comment: thanks a lot it works but i have to add 'asc' also ,this lodash library is common?seems its very useful

Comment: yeah its common and pretty much helpful have bunch of stuff out of the box, I have updated my answer and if you notice added `order?: string` ? mark in pipe transform to make order param optional.

Answer (score 4):

Angular does not provide a pipe for sorting items. You have to implement it yourself.
I think the best way to sort items is through a pipe.
That is a simple example:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class ArraySortPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
*ngFor="let value of myArr | sort:'fieldName'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
*ngFor="let s of rslt | order_by:'wind_park'">
```

Your Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'order_by'
})

export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, propName: string) {

   return value.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[propName] < b[propName]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[propName] === b[propName]) {
        return 0;
      } else if (a[propName] > b[propName]) {
        return 1;
      }
      // if(a[propName] > b[propName]) return 1
      // else return 1;
    });

  }
}
```

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knency?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Screenshot of working example:

[image]

Comment: @KamranKhatti : There are numerous way to sort it. I've done it in a one way and it's working functionally.

Answer (score 2):

Kamran Khatti answer totally works, but if you decided not to create custom pipe you can use angular build in keyvaluepipe, it accepts custom compare function as a paramter.

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let title of data | keyvalue:customsort"> 
  {{title.key}} ----- {{title.value.turbine_name}}
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
customsort = 
   ((a, b)=>{
     if(a.value[this.propName] === b.value[this.propName]){
       return 0
     }else if(a.value[this.propName] === null){
       return -1;
     }else if(b.value[this.propName] === null){
       return 1;
     }
    return a.value[this.propName].toString().localeCompare(b.value[this.propName].toString());
  });
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/keyvalue-pipe-ec99fg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: why its getting two values? a,b? and whats that-1 and 1?..thanks

Comment: It's just custom compareFunction, you can learn more about here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

```
*ngFor="let s of rslt| orderBy:['wind_park']">
```

Please refer to [No filter or orderBy Pipe in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) discussion
Or

Create your own `orderBy` Pipe [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612420/6810539)

If all these doesn't satisfy you, you can install `lodash` to your project and then create your own pipe as follow

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash'

@Pipe({
    name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
        return _.orderBy(array, ['field1', 'field2'], ['asc', 'desc']);
    }

}
```

and you can use it like

```
*ngFor="let s of rslt| orderBy:'wind_park'">
```

For this to work you need to import this to your module

```
@NgModule({
    ...,
    declarations: [OrderByPipe, ...],
    ...
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No pipe found with name 'orderBy'

Comment: I've added some useful links to my answer.

Comment: I see the no pipe for sort link referenced a lot on stack overflow, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't take to relevant documentation anymore.
I think I get why we don't want to do it, but it would be nice if someone had a more up to date reference. I haven't been able to find any actual information on it other than people saying not to do it with an out of date link.

Answer (score 0):

expanded version with localcompare suggestion:

```js
/*
 *ngFor="let c of oneDimArray | orderBy:'asc'"
 *ngFor="let c of arrayOfObjects | orderBy:'asc':'propertyName'"
*/
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy',
  pure: true
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private static sortOrderLocale(a: string, b: string, propertyName: string = ''): number {
    const lang = document.documentElement.lang;
    if (propertyName) {
      return a[propertyName].localeCompare(b[propertyName], lang, { ignorePunctuation: true });
    } else {
      return a.localeCompare(b, lang, { ignorePunctuation: true });
    }
  }

  transform(value: any[], order = '', propertyName?: string): any[] {
    if (!value || order === '' || !order) { return value; } // no array or object
    if (propertyName) {
      // object sort
      if (order === 'asc') {
        return value.sort((a: any, b: any) => OrderByPipe.sortOrderLocale(a, b, propertyName));
      }
      else {
        return value.sort((a: any, b: any) => OrderByPipe.sortOrderLocale(b, a, propertyName));
      }
    }
    else {
      // array sort
      if (order === 'asc') {
        return value.sort((a: any, b: any) => OrderByPipe.sortOrderLocale(a, b));
      }
      else {
        return value.sort((a: any, b: any) => OrderByPipe.sortOrderLocale(b, a));
      }
    }
  }
}
```