# Angular Sorting in HTML without the use of a Pipe

Tags: angular

[Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#do-not-add-filtering-and-sorting-logic-to-pipes) states that filtering and sorting should not be done in a Pipe due to the amount of calls per-second it will make, however, in the community, there is no shortage of examples and tutorials on doing it with a Pipe.

What is the ideal way to implement a pre/post-sort in a template, without mutating the original data and still have a reference to the original data?

I am coming from Vue.js, my first thought is a computed property, which may be close to a 'get' in angular??, but not sure.

Comment: One possibility is to put the data in an observable (BehaviorSubject) and build another observable from that where you map to filter/sort function, and use that observable in the template with the async pipe

Comment: Also, creating pure filter pipes isn't bad in itself, it's just not very convenient since it won't update when the array is updated. But if you overwrite the property with a new array, it will. Or you can use ChangeDetectionRef

Comment: @steve, you have two arrays `data` and `dataFiltered` (which is the array you use to loop). Each time you filter or sort, recalcule the `dataFiltered`

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/orderby-pipe-issue